# Why do I have two instances of NSWindowController for the one window?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I load a window programatically, as follows:

```
OddsWindowController *const controller = [[OddsWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"OddsWindow"];
```

In OddsWindowController, a subclass of NSWindowController, I'm logging self:

```
- (IBAction)showOdds:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"self = %@", self);
}

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"self = %@", self);
}
```

The two different log statements return different values for self, which implies I have two instances of my NSWindowController. What could be causing this? How can I stop this?

Comment: Do you also have an `OddsWindowController` object in your OddsWindow.xib? The xib should instead refer to the controller via the File's Owner placeholder. (The File's Owner will be your controller)

Comment: @MattR that was exactly the problem. Thanks